# Random grey screen on Ubuntu (Same one as VNC Grey Screen)

Tags: vpn, lightdm, vnc, openbox

I've been looking for an answer to my problem, but never found one because I don't know where it's from. I've looked at all my log files but can't find a log that look related to my problem!

[Here is a photo of my problematic screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8zBH.png)

I've seen this image on multiple topics, but all are related to a vnc server... In my case it's not in a vnc server...

It pop-ups randomly, and disappears on mouse mouvement (after I move the mouse, it goes back to normal).
It also goes back to normal when I restarted lightdm service (via SSH).

So you understand that my display manager is lightdm, and that I also have a VPN connection on my cpu.
I use Openbox as window manager, and the problem occurs on both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04!

If anyone have ever experienced a similar problem before I will be very happy to ear you,

Thank you everyone!

Comment: What video adapter do you use?

Comment: It happens on different devices (same SSD clone).
The GPU card of some is:
Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller

but the majority is 
Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620

Comment: Have you tried ubuntu other desktop managers? Maybe it's a bug of Openbox on Xorg server. I'll try Openbox now.

Comment: I've used Unity in the past, and I can't remember if it happens back then!
The fact that it's random makes it so difficult to reproduce... Only time will tell!
But it's a good idea, I will try to go back to Unity! 
If you could reproduces it, it will be great! But I can't bet on that :/
Thank you!